# Clang Static Analyzer False Positive with bit-fields (C-code)

Tags: c, clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am wondering if the following example is a Clang SA false positive, and if so, is there a way to suppress it?

The key here is that I am copying a structure containing bit-fields by casting it as a word instead of a field-by-field copy (or memcpy). Both field-by-field copy and memcpy doesn't trigger warnings, but copying as a word (after casting) raises an "uninitialized access" warning. This is on a embedded system where only word-access is possible and these types of word copies are common place.

Below is the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct my_fields_t {
  unsigned int f0: 16;
  unsigned int f1: 8;
  unsigned int f2: 8;
};

int main(void) {

  struct my_fields_t var1, var2;

  // initialize all the fields in var1.
  var1.f0 = 1;
  var1.f1 = 2;
  var1.f2 = 3;

  // Method #1: copy var1 -> var2 as a word (sizeof(unsigned int) = 4).
  unsigned int *src = (unsigned int *) &var1;
  unsigned int *dest = (unsigned int *) &var2;
  *dest = *src;

  // Method #2: copy var1->var2 field-by-field [NO SA WARNINGS]
  // var2.f0 = var1.f0;
  // var2.f1 = var1.f1;
  // var2.f2 = var1.f2;

  // Method #3: use memcpy to copy var1 to var2 [NO SA WARNINGS]
  // memcpy(&var2, &var1, sizeof(struct my_fields_t));

  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", var1.f0, var1.f1, var1.f2);
  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", var2.f0, var2.f1, var2.f2);  // <--- Function call argument is an uninitialized value
  printf("sizeof(unsigned int) = %ld\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

$ clang -Wall clang_sa.c

$ ./a.out
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
sizeof(unsigned int) = 4

$ scan-build clang clang_sa.c
scan-build: Using '<snipped>/clang-4.0' for static analysis
clang_sa.c:33:3: warning: Function call argument is an uninitialized value
  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", var2.f0, var2.f1, var2.f2);  // <--- Function call argument is an uninitialized value
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
```

In the above example, it is quite clear that all the fields in var2 will be initialized by the word copy. So, clang SA shouldn't complain about un-intialized access.

I appreciate any help/insight.

Comment: You are essentially asking if an `unsigned int` is allowed to alias a `unsigned int` bit field. I don't know - it might not be well-defined in the standard. Sound fix #1 is to avoid bit fields like the plague. Sound fix #2 is to avoid highly questionable pointer conversions.

Comment: Bit-fields have their place in embedded systems with limited memory, efficient instructions for inserting and extracting fields, compiler support, and where portability isn't a requirement. I could have written the example above without bit-fields (i.e., using uint16 and uint8 for f0-2 instead of bit-fields), and it would have the same result. The pointer conversions are beside the point of the actual question which was meant to generate a minimalistic example to illustrate the false positive.

Comment: No they don't have a place anywhere except as boolean blobs, where did you get that idea from? They particularly should not be used in hardware-related programming where they can cause the most harm. They add absolutely no advantage over bit-wise operators. Either will translate to the relevant instruction set. Except of course, bit-fields have a high probability to translating to the entirely wrong machine code, since you can't even know which bit that's msb. On many compilers like gcc, bit-fields also tend to cause memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of suppressing a specific warning, from the [documentation](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html#suppress_issue):

> **Q: How can I suppress a specific analyzer warning?**
>   There is currently no solid mechanism for suppressing an analyzer warning, although this is currently being investigated. ...

But on the next question, it shows you that you can mark a block of code to be skipped over during static analysis by surrounding the code with an `#ifdef` block:

> **Q: How can I selectively exclude code the analyzer examines?**
>   When the static analyzer is using clang to parse source files, it implicitly defines the preprocessor macro `__clang_analyzer__`. One can use this macro to selectively exclude code the analyzer examines. ...

So, you could do it like this:

```
#ifdef __clang_analyzer__
    #define COPY_STRUCT(DEST, SRC) (DEST) = (SRC)
#else
    #define COPY_STRUCT(DEST, SRC) do { \
        const unsigned int *src = (const void *)&(SRC); \
        unsigned int *dest = (void *)&(DEST); \
        *dest = *src; \
    } while(0)
#endif

COPY_STRUCT(var2, var1);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, this is for an embedded system where only word-aligned writes are possible (var2 = var1 won't necessarily generate code for word copies underneath). The original code uses volatile word pointers to ensure writes only occur at a word resolution - which I've simplified in the example shown. Regardless, this shouldn't have been flagged by Clang SA, isn't it? If this isn't a known limitation, I'll consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Casting to *volatile* `unsigned int *` will guarantee word-aligned writes. I've removed the volatile keyword in the example to simplify things and generate a minimalistic example. Thanks for the suggestion on `__clang_analyzer__`. I'll try this in addition filing this as a bug report to the Clang SA project.

Comment: The structures used should be word-aligned as well (using align directives). Again, these are details that are unnecessary for the crux of the problem (which is that Clang SA is throwing a false positive) - hence, they aren't in the example.

Comment: Thanks, for now I'll use `__clang_analyzer__` as a workaround and file a LLVM bug report for clang SA.